# VB Using "Runas"

Tags: vbscript, path

I am having a heck of a time getting some syntax correct here.

I have a small VB Script which prompts for credentials and then uses those credentials to run another vb script:

```
set objShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell") 
strAdminName = inputBox("What is your username (Domain\Username)") 
objShell.Run "runas /user:" & strAdminName & " ""Wscript.exe \\xxx.xx.xxx\dfs\Tumw-IS\Juniper Tools and Utilities\Juniper Removal Tools\delete_folders.vbs"" "
```

When I run the script everything works, except it can't find the script I am calling.  I get an error stating "There is no file extension in "\xxx.xx.xxx\dfs\tumw-is\Juniper"

Obviously the problem is in the fact that there are spaces in the file location and also that I am using a DFS link.  When I run this and target a VBS file with no spaces in the location it works fine.

I just can't get the syntax down to handle the DFS link or the spaces in the name.  I assume it's pretty straightforward, but I just can't get it to work.

Any ideas?

Thanks

-John

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
objShell.Run "runas /user:" & strAdminName & " ""Wscript.exe \""\\xxx.xx.xxx\dfs\Tumw-IS\Juniper Tools and Utilities\Juniper Removal Tools\delete_folders.vbs\"""""
```

Comment: Thanks for the response.

Unfortunately that did not work either.  Using the snip you gave me, I am not getting prompted for the password for the user contained in the strAdminName variable.

I have just decided to eliminate the spaces in the name of the folders where the target VBS script is located.

That seems to work fine with my original syntax.

-John

Comment: @user3583386 I figured it out and corrected my code above. You need to put a `\"` around any params to any programs you intend to launch. So your VBS filepath needs a `\"` on either side. Translating to VBScript, you need to double this quote, so it becomes `\""`. So this line ends with 5 quotes!

Comment: Thanks a ton Bond. I will give that a whirl and let you know. Like I said, it's not crucial as I can always remove the spaces in the directory names, but it would be nice to know how to do it in the event I run into a situation where I don't have the freedom to rename directories. -John

Comment: Awesome!!!  That absolutely worked.  I knew I was putting my slashes and quotes in the wrong place, I just couldn't figure out where they were supposed to go.

Thanks for you help!

-John